# Is the below relation true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I got a question. The question is:
If $a\gt b$ and $c\gt b$ , is there any possibility that; $\frac ab \gt \frac bc$ ?

I was having a go at it and further simplified it to-

$$ac \gt b^2$$

Then concluded that : 
The relation would only be true for $c \gt  b$ which is not included in the question. Is my conclusions correct? Or is there any way to prove that?

Comment: "$d$" is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $(a,b,c)=(1,-2,2).$

$1\cdot2>(-2)^2$ is wrong.

If $a>b>0$ and $c>b$, so $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{b}{c}$ is true because $ac>b^2$ is true:
$$ac-b^2=ac-bc+bc-b^2=c(a-b)+b(c-b)>0.$$

Comment: (Unrelated to question:) I want to get better at my inequalities. What sources would you recommend? You seem like the admirable expert on these things (though this question was particularly an easy one).

Comment: @Mr Pie I think the best way it's  just to read the AoPS's inequalities forum: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities

Comment: Thank you!!! :)